# Definition of unit of force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, units

As we know $1\ \mathrm{N}$ is the force which can accelerate $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ mass with $1\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ acceleration. But for which surface is this definition given? 
I mean a $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ book kept on table and other on ice will need different forces to be accelerate by $1\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ but by definition will they be equal?

Comment: The definition assumes absence of all other forces. Thus, 1 newton is the force required to accelerate a 1kg mass by $1 {m \over s^2}$ assuming no other forces, such as friction, are acting on the mass.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of force is under the assumption that there is no friction involved in the system. This means you can imagine the surface it is measured on as some kind of "super slippery ice" that has no frictional properties whatsoever. 
About the question whether the forces required to produce the same acceleration on different surfaces are the same: No they are not. Different surfaces have different frictional forces. Since in your scenario, the net force determines the acceleration, a greater force is needed to counteract a larger friction to produce the same acceleration.

Comment: Then which reference do we take when saying 1N force.I mean How will we know the load producing force is of how much newton.I can't really understand unit of force.

Comment: 1 newton is defined to be the NET force acting on a one kilogram object accelerating at 1 meter/second